# Compiling custom plugins for QGIS on Windows

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, compile

I've made my first plugin using plugin builder and I want to compile it. I read that I need two commands to do it under windows: `pyuic4` and `pyrcc4`. But when I use any of these commands I get this:

```
D:\Programy\QGis\bin>pyuic4 -o C:\Users\noaal\.qgis2\python\plugins\Test\Test.py
C:\Users\noaal\.qgis2\python\plugins\Test\Test_dialog_base.ui
ImportError: No module named site
```

I also read that I must change system path in windows, but I don't know to which location. So anyone have any clue?

Comment: You should have a _Makefile_ file within the directory of your plugin. Have you tried using just `$ make` instead of running those 2 commands separately?

Comment: How do you use '$ make' in cmd?

Comment: I will add this tutorial link although I think you might have got your information from here already: http://www.qgisworkshop.org/html/workshop/plugins_tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks a lot i did what you say and it worked. At first I don't have OSGeo4W, so there was a problem. BTW in windows you have to use only 'make' no '$ make'. Thanks again!

Comment: Most welcome buddy! And thanks for the correction, it's been a while since I used the plugin builder so had to refresh my memory :). Will post the above comments as an answer to hopefully help others in a similar situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method to compile custom-made plugins is to run the cmd prompt or the **OSGeo4W** shell via:

*Start* > *QGIS folder* > _OSGeo4W

Type `cd`, enter the directory of your plugin to make that the current directory and then type `make`. This should compile your plugin.